# Generate a list of lists from different flat lists with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have three lists, namely:

```
commands = ["ping", "exec", "someCmd"]
parameters = ["127.0.0.1", "mspaint", "someParam"]
iterations = ["2", "1", "3"]
```

as you can imagine, each item index correspond to same index in every list, so I want to have a list of lists where each element corresponds to each program, that is:

```
[['ping', '127.0.0.1', '2'], ['exec', 'mspaint', '1'], ['someCmd', 'someParam', '3']]
```

well, that's easy for a beginner like me with a for loop:

```
new_list = []
for c, _ in enumerate(commands):
    row = [commands[c], parameters[c], iterations[c]]
    new_list.append(row)
```

or the actually first that i came up with (i don't know if it's better or worse)

```
new_list = []
for c, command in enumerate(commands):
    row = [command, parameters[c], iterations[c]]
    new_list.append(row)
```

but I don't want to give up and tried to achieve the same with a list comprehension, which i did obviously bad, that's why I'm here

```
my_attempt = [[c, p, i] for c, p, i in commands, parameters, iterations]
```

but this surprisingly (for me) just make a list of list but every element is just like the input, that is:

```
[['ping', 'exec', 'asd'], ['127.0.0.1', 'paint', 'param'], ['2', '1', '3']]
```

Would you help me to fix this one, or suggest me other approaches?

Comment: You just want `list(zip(commands, parameters, iterations))`

Comment: If you wanted to actually tranform the elements, you'd do something like: `[c+p+i for c,p,i in zip(commands, parameters, iterations)]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga He's using Python 2. No need for the conversion to list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga zip returns a list of tuples, adding list() around it changes nothing. In any case I have to change the inner tuples to lists, right?

Comment: @alete yes, sorry, didn't see you were on Python 2. In Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator. To convert to lists, something as simple as  `map(list, zip(...))` would do.

Comment: @alete: You are iterating over the tuple `(commands, parameters, iterations)`, unpacking each into three variables. Had your input lists been longer you’d have had an exception instead.

Comment: Note that the literal transformation of your working code would have been `[[command, parameters[c], iterations[c]] for c, command in enumerate(commands)]`; moving the expression you append each iteration to the front.

Comment: Thanks everyone. If you want to sum up everything in this comments in one answer I would be glad to mark it as accepted, since the others are poor.

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is the `zip()` function

```
zip(commands,parameters,iterations)
```

will give you the result you need

Comment: actually the inner elements are tuples. Can I get lists?

Comment: Just convert them to a list `map(list, zip(commands,parameters,iterations))`

Answer (score 0):

```
zip(commands, parameters, iterations)
```